# RxJava getting multiple city weathers from Openweathermap

Tags: java, android, rx-java, rx-android

First of all, I am new on **rxjava**. I made a simple weather app which returns weather data of a city from **openweathermap API**. I combined with retrofit2 and rxjava. But I want to get multiple cities in order. Actually, I can do this by creating separated observable for example:

```
Observable<WeatherUpdated> observableAnkara = service.getWeatherData("Ankara",API_KEY);
observableAnkara.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<WeatherUpdated>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d)
                {
                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(WeatherUpdated weatherUpdated)
                {

                    tv.setText(weatherUpdated.getWeather().get(0).getDescription());
                }
                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                @Override
                public void onComplete()
                {


                }
            });


 Observable<WeatherUpdated> observableIstanbul = service.getWeatherData("Istanbul",API_KEY);
observableIstanbul
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribe(new Observer<WeatherUpdated>() {
                @Override
                public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onNext(WeatherUpdated weatherUpdated)
                {
                    tv_Istanbul.setText(weatherUpdated.getWeather().get(0).getDescription());
                    tv_Istanbul.setTextAlignment(View.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_CENTER);

                }

                @Override
                public void onError(Throwable e) {

                }

                @Override
                public void onComplete() {

                }
            });
```

After Ankara, I want to show Istanbul weather condition in the text. How can I do this? I searched it and there are many solutions like concat, startWith, zip but which one is the correct? I am confused about them.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Use zip operator.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a city controls map:

```
    Map<String, Control> cityControls= getCityControls();
```

and then

```
Observable
            .fromArray(cities.keySet().toArray())
            .flatMap(city -> service.getWeatherData(city, API_KEY).map(data ->  new Pair<String, String>(city, data.getWeather().get(0).getDescription())))
            .observeOn(...)
            .subscribe(data -> citiesControls[data.getKey()].setText(data.getValue()))
```

Comment: I could not change my observable like this.. Could you please write explitly

Comment: Please expand your answer and add some commentary or documentation, so everybody understands what your answer is about.